# Dynamically assign table to model in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, reporting, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am still new to Laravel and Eloquent.  I am working on a project to display reports.  I have backend jobs that are dropping and creating tables with report data.  Each table is it's own report so that in Laravel I can just select one table to display the report.

For each report I am defining it in a report listings table with a friendly name for the report and the table the report lives in.  Is it possible to have one master report model that loads the model for each report?

Alternatively it is possible to have a "skeleton" model with the same methods (filter,sort,order) instead of creating a model for each report table?

Looking for the best architecture to tackle this leveraging Laravel. Thanks!

Comment: So I found that I can just call setTable() in my controller but then I can't extract data by running Report::all()  I need to do $report->all().

Not sure what the difference is or if I am losing anything by doing that though.

Comment: If you are not interested in $fillable method of Model than you are fine.
You can not retrieve data using `ModelName::all()` reason is you are a binding table at run time.

You can do

$report = new Report;
$report->setTable('TABLE_NAME');

$report->all();